# Google Actions - Disabling "Sign in required for welcome intent" doesn't work

Tags: google-account, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk, google-assist-api

I'm developing a Google Action, and while I was implementing account linking, I turned on the "Sign in required for welcome intent" checkbox in the API.AI settings panel.

So the user flow was:

> User: Talk to cool app
>
> -> User gets the account linking message

Now that my setup is working, I want to postpone account linking to be requested on a specific action in my app, and not on the welcome intent.

So what I want to happen is (fictive dialog :) ):

> User: Talk to cool app
>
> My app: Hi, I am cool app, what can I do for
> you?
>
> User: Be cool
>
> My app: I am so cool. Would you like to link
> accounts?
>
> User: Yes
>
> --> User gets the account linking message

**I disabled the checkbox, but the app is still requesting to link on the welcome intent. Is it a bug in API.AI? Is it possible at all to ask for account linking in a later stage in the app? And if so, how?**

[image: I disabled this checkbox]

But this is still happening:

[image: Simulator result]